# Como documentar/descrever colunas no Swagger

Tags: node.js, api, documentação, swagger

Estou realizando a documentação de uma API utilizando o Swaggwer, porém, não encontrei uma forma de descrever o que é cada campo do json.

Seguindo o exemplo abaixo, esse é o json que o Swagger gera de exemplo com os dados da minha api:
[Json exemplo gerado pelo Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdzCR.png)

Mas precisaria descrever o que é cada campo, pois o outro desenvolvedor nem sempre saberá o que significa um "cd_emp" ou um "qtde_pend_pedv" por exemplo.

Mais ou menos o que eu queria, seria algo assim, como um comentário em frente a cada campo:
[Exemplo de descrição dos campos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsCbv.png)

É possível ou há alguma maneira parecida que possa usar para descrever cada coluna?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: você pode adicionar informações na sua model que devem aparecer na descrição dos contratos (*schemas*), por exemplo usando `ApiModelProperty`. Tem um package para `nodejs` que lê isso, dê uma procurada